# Kendo grid with MVVM, binding column visibility

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have a kendo grid using MVVM.
My problem is I can't seem to set column visibility using the hidden attribute and an expression:

```
data-columns=
             "[{'template':'# if (User!=null) { # #=User.Name# # } #',
             'title':'User', 'hidden': User==null}
```

The template works, but the 'hidden' attribute doesn't seem to.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: User==null will be executed in the global context - is a User var accessible there?

Comment: Yeah, I could make one available. Is there no way to get the expression to evaluate a bind time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative, you could bind to the `dataBinding` or `dataBound` event to hide the column conditionally:

```
data-bind="events:{ dataBinding: onDataBinding }"
```

View model:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    User: null,
    showHideUserColumn: function (e) {
        var grid = e.sender;

        if (this.User) {
            grid.showColumn("User");
        } else {
            grid.hideColumn("User");
        }
    },
    onDataBinding: function (e) {
        this.showHideUserColumn(e);

        // if you want to track changes, (re)bind change tracking
        this.unbind("change", this.showHideUserColumn);
        this.bind("change", this.showHideUserColumn);
    }
});
```

Comment: The assumption here is that the column is a field-based column. Do you know how to get this to work if the column is a command column and doesn't have a field name? (

Answer (score 4):

Only the properties specified via the `data-bind` attribute participate in MVVM change tracking. The other data attributes are mapped to widget configuration properties and are not evaluated against the view model.

Currently there is no binding which will allow you to hide and show grid columns.